# removing certain escaped characters in ruby string using gsub and regex

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I am dealing with some long strings in ruby which can have some weird escaped characters. For example, one string that is causing problems for me is like:

```
s = "foobar \240 \241 \242 foobar\nfoobar"
puts s
foobar ? ? ? foobar
foobar
```

I am trying to get rid of the weird `\240`, `\241`, `\242` characters in the above string. Can someone tell me the regex for gsub that does that? Note: I want to retain the \n, just want to get rid of anything that has a backslash followed by a number.

Essentially, is there a way to get rid of all substrings of the form `"\[one or more digits]"`

This quirk has been annoying me for a while now. I can do it for a given number, but cannot find the regex which makes a general substitution for any number after the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex: `\\\d+`. It matches `\240`, `\241`, `\242`.

It means `Literal \, any digit one or more repetitions`.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work: I am doing it like this - a.gsub("\\\d+","")
=> "foobar \240 \241 \242 foobar\nfoobar" and have tried a.gsub(/\\\d+/,"")
=> "foobar \240 \241 \242 foobar\nfoobar"

Comment: Also tried "\240".gsub(Regexp.new("\\\d+"),"")
=> "\240" which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Regexp class to create a pattern for your specific range of characters and replace that.

```
s = "foobar \240 \241 \242 foobar\nfoobar"
min = 240
max = 242
pattern = Regexp.new "[\\#{min}-\\#{max}]"
puts s.gsub(pattern, '*')
```

will output:

```
foobar * * * foobar
foobar
```